# Zoom and scroll ImageView inside the ScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview, zooming

The screen has an aimView centered. I need to correct the ScrollView:

1. After zoom - the image should be centered horizontally / vertically
   if there are distances from the imageView to the edges of the screen
2. After the zoom, it should be possible to scroll the ScrollView so
   that any part of the imageView can get under the aimView
3. When opening the screen, the zoom was set so that the image took up the
   maximum possible area

now it looks like this:

[image: Scroll ImageView]

```
class ScrollViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    var imageView: UIImageView!
    var image: UIImage!
    var aimView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.delegate = self
        setupScrollView()

        image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "apple")
        imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        setupImageView()

        aimView = UIView()
        setupAimView()
    }

    func setupScrollView() {
        scrollView.backgroundColor = .yellow
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor)
        ])

        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 10
        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.1
        scrollView.zoomScale = 1.0
    }

    func setupImageView() {
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.addSubview(imageView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: image.size.width),
            imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: image.size.height),
            imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor),
            imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor),
            imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor),
            imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor)
        ])
    }

    func setupAimView() {
        aimView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        aimView.backgroundColor = .green
        aimView.alpha = 0.7
        aimView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        view.addSubview(aimView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            aimView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            aimView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 100),
            aimView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: aimView.heightAnchor),
            aimView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
        ])
    }

    // MARK: - UIScrollViewDelegate

    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        imageView
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to approach this... one way:

- use a `UIView` as the scroll view's "content"
- constrain that "content" view on all 4 sides to the scroll view's content layout guide
- embed the imageView in that "content" view
- constrain the Top and Leading of the imageView so it will appear at the bottom-right corner of the "aim" view, when the content view is scrolled to `0,0`
- constrain the Trailing and Bottom of the imageView so it will appear at the top-left corner of the "aim" view, when the content view is scrolled to its max x and y

To give you an idea...

[image][image]

[image][image]

The dashed-outline rect is the scroll view frame. The green rect is the "aim" view. The yellow rect is the "content" view.

We won't be able to use the scroll view's built-in zooming, because it would also "zoom" the space between the image view's edges and the content view. Instead, we can add a `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` to the scroll view. When the user pinches to zoom, we'll take the gesture's `.scale` value and use that to change the width and height constants of the imageView. Since we've constrained that imageView to the content view, the content view will grow / shrink *without* changing the spacing on the sides.

Here is an example implementation (it requires an asset image named "apple"):

```
class PinchScroller: UIScrollView {
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        let pinchGesture = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePinchGesture(_:)))
        self.addGestureRecognizer(pinchGesture)
    }
    
    var scaleStartCallback: (()->())?
    var scaleChangeCallback: ((CGFloat)->())?

    // assuming minimum scale of 1.0
    var minScale: CGFloat = 1.0
    // assuming maximum scale of 5.0
    var maxScale: CGFloat = 5.0

    private var curScale: CGFloat = 1.0
    
    @objc private func handlePinchGesture(_ gesture:UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
        
        if gesture.state == .began {
            // inform controller scaling started
            scaleStartCallback?()
        }
        
        if gesture.state == .changed {
            // inform controller the scale changed
            let val: CGFloat = gesture.scale - 1.0
            let scale = min(maxScale, max(minScale, curScale + val))
            scaleChangeCallback?(scale)
        }
        
        if gesture.state == .ended {
            // update current scale value
            let val: CGFloat = gesture.scale - 1.0
            curScale = min(maxScale, max(minScale, curScale + val))
        }
        
    }
    
}

class AimViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var scrollView: PinchScroller!
    var imageView: UIImageView!
    var contentView: UIView!
    var aimView: UIView!
    
    var imageViewTopConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var imageViewLeadingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var imageViewTrailingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var imageViewBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    var imageViewWidthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var imageViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    var imageViewWidthFactor: CGFloat = 1.0
    var imageViewHeightFactor: CGFloat = 1.0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // make sure we can load the image
        guard let img = UIImage(named: "apple") else {
            fatalError("Could not load image!!!")
        }
        
        scrollView = PinchScroller()
        imageView = UIImageView()
        contentView = UIView()
        aimView = UIView()
        
        [scrollView, imageView, contentView, aimView].forEach {
            $0?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }
        
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.addSubview(contentView)
        contentView.addSubview(imageView)
        scrollView.addSubview(aimView)
        
        // init image view width constraint
        imageViewWidthConstraint = imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0.0)
        imageViewHeightConstraint = imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0.0)
        
        // to handle non-1:1 ratio images
        if img.size.width > img.size.height {
            imageViewHeightFactor = img.size.height / img.size.width
        } else {
            imageViewWidthFactor = img.size.width / img.size.height
        }
        
        // init image view Top / Leading / Trailing / Bottom constraints
        imageViewTopConstraint = imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 0.0)
        imageViewLeadingConstraint = imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0)
        imageViewTrailingConstraint = imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0)
        imageViewBottomConstraint = imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0)
        
        let safeG = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        let contentG = scrollView.contentLayoutGuide
        let frameG = scrollView.frameLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // constrain scroll view to all 4 sides of safe area
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            // constrain "content" view to all 4 sides of scroll view's content layout guide
            contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            // activate these constraints
            imageViewTopConstraint,
            imageViewLeadingConstraint,
            imageViewTrailingConstraint,
            imageViewBottomConstraint,
            
            imageViewWidthConstraint,
            imageViewHeightConstraint,
            
            // "aim" view: 200x200, centered in scroll view frame
            aimView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0),
            aimView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: aimView.widthAnchor),
            aimView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: frameG.centerXAnchor),
            aimView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: frameG.centerYAnchor),
            
        ])
        
        // set the image
        imageView.image = img
        
        // disable interaction for "aim" view
        aimView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        // aim view translucent background color
        aimView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green.withAlphaComponent(0.25)
        
        // probably don't want scroll bouncing
        scrollView.bounces = false
        
        // set the scaling callback closures
        scrollView.scaleStartCallback = { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else {
                return
            }
            self.didStartScale()
        }
        scrollView.scaleChangeCallback = { [weak self] v in
            guard let self = self else {
                return
            }
            self.didChangeScale(v)
        }
        
        contentView.backgroundColor = .yellow
        
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        // set constraint constants here, after all view have been initialized
        let aimSize: CGSize = aimView.frame.size
        
        imageViewWidthConstraint.constant = aimSize.width * imageViewWidthFactor
        imageViewHeightConstraint.constant = aimSize.height * imageViewHeightFactor
        
        let w = (scrollView.frame.width - aimSize.width) * 0.5 + aimSize.width
        let h = (scrollView.frame.height - aimSize.height) * 0.5 + aimSize.height
        
        imageViewTopConstraint.constant = h
        imageViewLeadingConstraint.constant = w
        imageViewTrailingConstraint.constant = -w
        imageViewBottomConstraint.constant = -h
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // center the content in the scroll view
            let xOffset = aimSize.width - ((aimSize.width - self.imageView.frame.width) * 0.5)
            let yOffset = aimSize.height - ((aimSize.height - self.imageView.frame.height) * 0.5)
            self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: xOffset, y: yOffset)
        }
    }
    
    private var startContentOffset: CGPoint = .zero
    private var startSize: CGSize = .zero
    
    func didStartScale() -> Void {
        startContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset
        startSize = imageView.frame.size
    }
    
    func didChangeScale(_ scale: CGFloat) -> Void {
        // all sizing is based on the "aim" view
        let aimSize: CGSize = aimView.frame.size
        // starting scroll offset
        var cOffset = startContentOffset
        // starting image view width and height
        let w = startSize.width
        let h = startSize.height
        // new image view width and height
        let newW = aimSize.width * scale * imageViewWidthFactor
        let newH = aimSize.height * scale * imageViewHeightFactor
        // change image view width based on pinch scaling
        imageViewWidthConstraint.constant = newW
        imageViewHeightConstraint.constant = newH
        // adjust content offset so image view zooms from its center
        let xDiff = (newW - w) * 0.5
        let yDiff = (newH - h) * 0.5
        cOffset.x += xDiff
        cOffset.y += yDiff
        // update scroll offset
        scrollView.contentOffset = cOffset
    }
}
```

Give that a try. If it comes close to what you're going for, then you've got a place to start.

---

**Edit**

After playing around a bit more with `scrollView.contentInset`, this is a much simpler approach. It uses the standard `UIScrollView` with its zoom/pan functionality, and doesn't require any extra "zoom" calculations or constraint changes:

```
class AimInsetsViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    var imageView: UIImageView!

    var aimView: UIView!
    
    var imageViewTopConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var imageViewLeadingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var imageViewTrailingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var imageViewBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    var imageViewWidthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var imageViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    var imageViewWidthFactor: CGFloat = 1.0
    var imageViewHeightFactor: CGFloat = 1.0
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        var imageName: String = ""
        imageName = "apple"

        // testing different sized images
        //imageName = "apple228x346"
        //imageName = "zoom640x360"
        
        // make sure we can load the image
        guard let img = UIImage(named: imageName) else {
            fatalError("Could not load image!!!")
        }
        
        scrollView = UIScrollView()
        imageView = UIImageView()
        aimView = UIView()
        
        [scrollView, imageView, aimView].forEach {
            $0?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }
        
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
        scrollView.addSubview(aimView)
        
        // init image view width constraint
        imageViewWidthConstraint = imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0.0)
        imageViewHeightConstraint = imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0.0)
        
        // to handle non-1:1 ratio images
        if img.size.width > img.size.height {
            imageViewHeightFactor = img.size.height / img.size.width
        } else {
            imageViewWidthFactor = img.size.width / img.size.height
        }
        
        let safeG = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        let contentG = scrollView.contentLayoutGuide
        let frameG = scrollView.frameLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // constrain scroll view to all 4 sides of safe area
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            // constrain "content" view to all 4 sides of scroll view's content layout guide
            imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            imageViewWidthConstraint,
            imageViewHeightConstraint,
            
            // "aim" view: 200x200, centered in scroll view frame
            aimView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0),
            aimView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: aimView.widthAnchor),
            aimView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: frameG.centerXAnchor),
            aimView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: frameG.centerYAnchor),
            
        ])
        
        // set the image
        imageView.image = img
        
        // disable interaction for "aim" view
        aimView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        
        // aim view translucent background color
        aimView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green.withAlphaComponent(0.25)
        
        // probably don't want scroll bouncing
        scrollView.bounces = false
        
        // delegate
        scrollView.delegate = self
        
        // set max zoom scale
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 10.0
        
        // set min zoom scale to less than 1.0
        //  if you want to allow image view smaller than aim view
        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
        
        // scroll view background
        scrollView.backgroundColor = .yellow
        
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        // set constraint constants, scroll view insets and initial content offset here,
        //  after all view have been initialized
        let aimSize: CGSize = aimView.frame.size
        
        // aspect-fit image view to aim view
        imageViewWidthConstraint.constant = aimSize.width * imageViewWidthFactor
        imageViewHeightConstraint.constant = aimSize.height * imageViewHeightFactor
        
        // set content insets
        let f = aimView.frame
        scrollView.contentInset = .init(top: f.origin.y + f.height,
                                        left: f.origin.x + f.width,
                                        bottom: f.origin.y + f.height,
                                        right: f.origin.x + f.width)
    
        // center image view in aim view
        var c = scrollView.contentOffset
        c.x -= (aimSize.width - imageViewWidthConstraint.constant) * 0.5
        c.y -= (aimSize.height - imageViewHeightConstraint.constant) * 0.5
        scrollView.contentOffset = c
        
    }

}

extension AimInsetsViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return imageView
    }
}
```

I think that will be much closer to what you're going for.

Comment: Gestures are very cool added and interaction between them is configured. But they take turns. Pinch only or scroll only. And while zooming inside the scrollView, you can simultaneously zoom in and scroll it.

Comment: @flyer2001 - see the **Edit** to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve this is by using a PDFView.

Code:

```
import PDFKit


let pdfView = PDFView(frame: self.view.bounds)
pdfView.displayDirection = .vertical
pdfView.displayMode = .singlePage
pdfView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        
if let image = UIImage(named: "sample"),
   let pdfPage = PDFPage(image: image) {
            
     let pdfDoc = PDFDocument()
     pdfDoc.insert(pdfPage, at: 0)
            
     pdfView.document = pdfDoc
     pdfView.autoScales = true
     pdfView.minScaleFactor = pdfView.scaleFactorForSizeToFit
            
}
        
self.view.addSubview(pdfView)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This is a very capacious solution, but I cannot change the position of the pdfView relative to aimView. Is it possible to add padding from the edges like in scrollView?

Answer (score 0):

First I added padding after zoom (scrollView.contentInset)

```
    var horizontalPadding: CGFloat { view.bounds.width / 4 }
    var verticalPadding: CGFloat { view.bounds.height / 4 }

    func setPadding() {
        let imageViewSize = imageView.frame.size
        let scrollViewSize = scrollView.bounds.size

        let verticalPadding = imageViewSize.height < scrollViewSize.height
            ? (scrollViewSize.height - imageViewSize.height) / 2
            : self.verticalPadding
        let horizontalPadding = imageViewSize.width < scrollViewSize.width
            ? (scrollViewSize.width - imageViewSize.width) / 2
            : self.horizontalPadding

        let toAimViewWidthSpacing = aimView.frame.origin.x
        let toAimViewHeightSpacing = aimView.frame.origin.y

        scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(
            top: verticalPadding + toAimViewHeightSpacing ,
            left: horizontalPadding + toAimViewWidthSpacing ,
            bottom: verticalPadding + toAimViewHeightSpacing ,
            right: horizontalPadding + toAimViewWidthSpacing)
    }
```

Secondly, added delegate methods scrollViewDidZoom and scrolViewDidEndZooming

```
    func scrollViewDidZoom(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        setPadding()
    }

    func scrollViewDidEndZooming(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, with view: UIView?, atScale scale: CGFloat) {
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(
            width: imageView.frame.width,
            height: imageView.frame.height)
    }
```

And finaly add a method to center the image which added to the viewDidLayoutSubviews()

```
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        centerImageInScrollView()
    }

    func centerImageInScrollView() {
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize( width: imageView.frame.width, height: imageView.frame.height)
        let newContentOffsetX = (scrollView.contentSize.width - scrollView.frame.size.width) / 2
        let newContentOffsetY = (scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height) / 2
        scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: newContentOffsetX, y: newContentOffsetY), animated: true)
    }
```

The entire code is [here](https://gist.github.com/flyer2001/aa91d8867fe8c0bfba39f7de22ec85b0)!

how it looks

[image: Zoom ZcrollView]